# How to set stacked bar chart graph "Fit to page size" report using Jaspersoft studio?

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

How to set stacked bar chart graph "Fit to page size" (the graph should cover the whole page and stretch according to data without overlapping) in jasper report using Jaspersoft studio ?

I have taken "Chart_elememt" inside "Frame_element". I have tried changing the appearance properties of Chart_element and Frame_element but none of them worked.

**Basically, I had two graphs in one .jrxml which created the problem of x-y axis (was not able to start both the graphs by "0" x-axis i.e. from bottom of my page), so I created sub-report and moved the second graph into it. Now my first graph is working fine, but second graph (in sub-report) is still reflecting shrinked and overlapping data though I have kept same properties as I have for my first graph.**

[In sub-report - Shrinked Graph (Data overlapping and is not Fit-to-page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDWw2.png)

[In main report - Expected Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nIJk.png)

Main report source code where subreport is called:

```
         <subreport>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="1002" width="1088" height="20">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <subreportParameter name="start">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{start}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="end">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{end}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["QuantitéRelancesCause_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
```

Subreport source code:

```
<title>
    <band height="1051">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="410" y="10" width="250" height="40">
                <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="20"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Quantité relances/cause]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="80" width="1090" height="904" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <stackedBarChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="false" evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="80" width="1080" height="824">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.interval" value="1"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{DESCRIPTION}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{DESCRIPTION}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNT(DISTINCT(PIECE_ID))}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot isShowLabels="true" isShowTickLabels="true" isShowTickMarks="true">
                    <plot labelRotation="-45.0"/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat labelRotation="-45.0">
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </stackedBarChart>
        </frame>
    </band>
</title>
```